# Where to save file that gets updated nightly?

Tags: django

I have a cron job that runs nightly and updates a json file, the json file is used by the site to build a map. Right now I am saving it to the MEDIA_ROOT is this a good practice, if not where should this file be saved to?

Answer (score 0):

MEDIA_ROOT is the absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold **user-uploaded files**. It's really meant for files that should be served publicly by the web server.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#media-root)

It really depends on your project structure. I would put such a file in {BASE_DIR}/var/.